# Embedding proper algebraic spaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Does every proper algebraic space (over a field, say) admit a closed immersion into a smooth proper algebraic space?

Remark: Of course, if we say "projective" instead of "proper" then the answer is tautologically "yes":  we can take the ambient variety to be some projective n-space.  But I'm curious about the general case.

Comment: No : there are proper normal surfaces $S$ with trivial Picard group (see for instance [Stefan Schröer, On non-projective normal surfaces]). If you could embed $S$ in a smooth and proper $X$, you could choose a Weil (hence Cartier) effective divisor in $X$ intersecting $S$ but not containing it, showing that the Picard group of $S$ is not trivial.

Comment: Are you sure that this exclude the possibility of embedding $S$ into a smooth *algebraic space*? It seems to me that this argument only works if $X$ is a *scheme*, or I am missing something?

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi Ah you are absolutely right ! Sorry !

Answer (score 6):

I do not know the general answer to this interesting question.

However, there are surely examples of proper algebraic *varieties* that admit no embeddeding into smooth *schemes*.

Look for instance to [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0406384) by Roth and Vakil, page 11.

Note that in the paper the authors claim that their example admits no embedding into a smooth algebraic space; however, their proof actually only work for smooth schemes, see the corrigendum in Vakil's webpage [here](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/preprints.html).

Comment: Thanks for the comments and pointer to the literature.  I guess the answer may not be known -- too bad!